# How to convert String into JsValue in Play Framework

Tags: string, scala, playframework, type-conversion, jsvalue

Is it possible at all to convert a `String` to a `JsValue`? And how would I do so? I've been trying `.asInstanceOf[JsValue]` but that doesn't appear to be working

I get the following error:

> [ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>   play.api.libs.json.JsValue]

Any ideas?

Comment: `Json.toJson(v)` for any value `v` whose type is supported (that's to say is whose type provided a `Writes` instance)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala - convert String to Json using Play json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42168817/scala-convert-string-to-json-using-play-json)

Answer (score 6):

if the string is a representation of a json object, eg:

`val jsonString: String = """{"key": "value"}"""`

then it can be converted to a value of type JsValue

`val jsonObject: JsValue = Json.parse(jsonString)`

and you can access the values in the json with path operator

`println(jsonObject \ "key")`

Answer (score 4):

A way to construct JsValue from String is to use the `play.api.libs.json.JsString` case class.

Namely, `JsString("abc")` can be used wherever the JsValue representation of `"abc"` is needed.